# How to detect which process changes,renames or create a file?

Tags: c++

There are tools to detect file behaviors in C(SHChangeNotify) or C#(FileSystemWatcher), which can notify events of create or rename.

But we have no knowledge of which process raises notification in c++.

My application wants to know whether the file is changed by me or other processes. I need to distinguish behaviors raised by different processes.

Comment: You can't.  Only can tell user that creates a file and not the process.  If you capture the event when a file has changed you may be able to get the parent process id.

Comment: There's no such functionality in C++. Use OS-specific APIs - they might have something.

Comment: @jdweng how to get the process holding the changed file?

Answer (score 0):

You need to hook the events in kernel [minispy](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/filesys/miniFilter/minispy) or subscribe to wmi events [msdn : wmi](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393013(v=vs.85).aspx)